# NightmareJS .then executing before .evaluate is finished

Tags: javascript, nightmare

Im trying to make nightmare js do a `.evaluate`, then after it returns a value execute a `.then(function(varFromEvaluate){})` but the `.then` function executes before the evaluate is even done.

This also makes it so i cant get the value that the evaluate returns, even if i do `.wait` instead of `.evaluate` it just returns undefined for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
nightmare
 .evaluate(function(){
     return true
 }).then(function(isTrue){
     console.log(isTrue) //result is false
 })
```

Comment: What happens when you add an `.end()` before your `.then()` statement?

Comment: try: `nightmare
 .evaluate(function(){
     return true
 })
.end()
.then(function(isTrue){
     console.log(isTrue) //result is false
 })` see doc https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare

Comment: @AagamJain That doesnt work, it just ends the nightmare instance and the .then isnt executed

Comment: @DavidR It ends the nightmare instance and the .then function doesnt get executed

Comment: See end documentation, They clearly said that if you are using `then()`, It must be call after `end()`. see https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#end. or alternatively you can also pass callback in `end()` itself and it is same as `then()`.

Comment: @AagamJain I think you misunderstood what they are saying. ".then() must be called after .end() to run the .end() task.". This just means that if you do .end() without a .then after it, the .end wont execute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is never in the `.evaluate` function.

We cannot figure out what is actually wrong here, because the actual code inside .evaluate function is not shared. Once tried with basic example, it works flawlessly. Check your original code.

Code to test this out,

```
const Nightmare = require("nightmare");
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
nightmare
  .goto("about:blank")
  .evaluate(() => true)
  .then(isTrue => console.log({ isTrue }));
```

The result:
[image]